# puppeteer click button but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to click the button

[image: 1]

I tried this and it worked on website

```
document.querySelector('.search_wrap .search_bar .search_input > .btn_search').click()
```

so I tried

```
await page.evaluate(() => {document.querySelector('.search_wrap .search_bar .search_input > .btn_search').click()})
```

but it didn't work so I tried this code again

```
await page.click('.search_wrap .search_bar .search_input > .btn_search')
```

it didn't work too. what did I miss?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `I tried this and it worked on website` wasn't that the desired effect?

Comment: Just because it works on the site doesn't mean it'll work in Puppeteer, for many reasons, including but not limited to iframes or delayed loading. Please share the page URL.